# Integrability of the Newton potential

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

For $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we define the *Newton potential* as follows:$$N(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\log|x|}{2\pi}, &  n=2 \\[10pt]  \frac{|x|^{2-n}}{(2-n)\omega_n}, &  n>2\end{cases}$$

where $\omega_n$ denoted to the volume of the *n*-ball. Moreover, let $\chi_r$ denote to the characteristic function of the ball $B(0,r)$.

Now my lecture notes say **(for $n>2$)**

1. $\chi_r N \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (or, more general, $L^p$, where $p<\frac{n}{n-2}$) and
2. $(1-\chi_r)N \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (or, more general, $L^p$, where $p>\frac{n}{n-2}$)

Since $N \in L_\mathrm{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, it follows immediately that $\chi_r N \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $r>0$.

How do I see the other claims?

Comment: Is claim 2 supposed to be $(1-\chi_r)N\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) $? Anyway, it is not true when $n=2$.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to show claims 1 and 2 for $n>2$ only. So, yes and yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the following formula, which is true for a radial function $f$ (that is, which depends only of the norm of the argument):
$$\int_{B(0,r)}f(x)dx=c_n\int_0^r\widetilde f(t)t^{n-1}dt,$$
where $c_n$ is a constant I leave to determine, and $\widetilde f$ is such that $f(x)=\widetilde f(|x|)$, where $|\cdot|$ is the euclidian norm.

For $n=2$, $\chi_r N\in L^p$ if and only if $\int_0^rt^{n-1}|\ln t|^pdt $ is finite that is, if and only if $\int_0^1e^{u(n-1)}e^uu^pdu$ is finite, which is always the case.

For $n>2$, $\chi_rN\in L^p$ if and only if $\int_0^1t^{n-1}t^{(2-n)p}dt<\infty$ which is equivalent to $\int_0^1\frac 1{t^{1-(n+(2-n)p)}}dt<\infty$, which occurs if and only if $n+(2-n)p>0$.

We have that 
\begin{align}
(1-\chi_r)N\in L^p&\Leftrightarrow \int_1^{+\infty} t^{n-1}t^{(2-n)p}dt<\infty\\
&\Leftrightarrow \int_1^{+\infty}\frac 1{t^{1-(n+(2-n)p)}}dt<\infty \\
&\Leftrightarrow n+(2-n)p<0.
\end{align}

Comment: For $n=2$, I think the first integral is finite iff $\int_{-\infty}^{\log{r}} e^{u(n-1)} e^u |u|^p du$ is finite what is not clear (at least for me as $p>>1$). However, the idea for $n>2$ works fine (here the integral goes from $0$ to $r$ or $r$ to $+\infty$).